# Add a horizontal line after click button clone table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to put a horizontal line on top of a clone table without adding any new html tag such as `<p>`, `<div>` or any similar. I have no clue to make it happening.

I've also tried by adding a `style.border` when a `click` event is detected, but it seen like only can get the `id` after the `html` page was loaded. Probably I'm doing something wrong here.

This is my code:

```js
function newtable(id) {

  var table = document.getElementById(id).lastChild;
  var tr = table.lastChild;

  var lastId = Number(tr.getAttribute('id').split('_')[1]);

  var trClone = tr.cloneNode(true);
  trClone.setAttribute('id', id + '_' + (lastId + 1));
  trClone.lastChild.childNodes[0].setAttribute('onclick', 'remove(' + id + ',' + (lastId + 1) + ')');
  table.appendChild(trClone);

  var b = document.getElementById(id).style.borderBottomColor = "red"; //i try to add horizontal line here every time this function is trigger.

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table id="1">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span>Name</span> <input type="text" value="Peterson" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span>Country</span><input type="text" value="England" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span>Email</span><input type="text" value="Peterson@gmail.com" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="newtable(10)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Expected result every time click on add button will clone table and draw horizontal line on top of new clone table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to fix some minor errors:

1. I replaced the `lastChild()` with `table.rows[lastRowIndex]` to get the last element of a table.
2. Added  a new `newId` to update the ids.
3. I'm using `mainTable.insertRow(mainTable.rows.length);` to add a row in the `<tbody>` of the `main-tbl`.
4. Added a `.adder` class to the `<tr>` element that contains the button.
5. I filter the first and last children also the `.adder` class using this query: `tr:not(.adder):not(:first-child):not(:last-child)`

Here is a working example:

```js
let mainTable = document.getElementById('main-tbl');

function addNewRow(id) {
  let table = document.getElementById('inner-tbl');
  let lastRowIndex = table.rows.length - 1;
  let trOrigin = table.rows[lastRowIndex];

  let lastId = Number(trOrigin.getAttribute('id').split('_')[1]);
  let newId = 'item_' + (lastId + 1);
  trOrigin.setAttribute('id', newId);

  let trClone = trOrigin.cloneNode(true);
  let lastCellIndex = trClone.cells.length - 1;

  // Insert a row in the table at the last row
  let newRow = mainTable.insertRow(mainTable.rows.length);
  newRow.setAttribute('id', newId);
  newRow.innerHTML = trClone.innerHTML;
  newRow.cells[lastCellIndex].setAttribute('onclick', 'remove(' + id + ',' + (lastId + 1) + ')');
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#main-tbl>tbody>tr:not(.adder):not(:first-child):not(:last-child)>td {
  // border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: red;
}

#main-tbl {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table id="main-tbl">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table id="inner-tbl">
          <tr id="item_0">
            <td>
              <span>Name</span> <input type="text" value="Peterson" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span>Country</span><input type="text" value="England" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span>Email</span><input type="text" value="Peterson@gmail.com" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="adder">
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addNewRow()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the answer you share  will only add the line in the end of the table, while click second time the horizontal line will go to the second table

Comment: You have two tables, which one you want to add those cloned `<tr>`? let's call the first table `main_table` and the second table `inner_table` just tell me which one and I will fix my answer accordingly

Comment: clone table will be  in inner_table and table will have new id after clone

Comment: @Victor, I'm sorry I can't understand you. Don't just tell me ***table***. Please use this expression `origin: inner_table`  to  `destination: main_table`. It is this what you want, right?

Comment: sorry for my bad reply. yes as what you describe is correct

Comment: @Teocci I think the op needs that line just before appending the table not after appending the table. This might fix what op wants

Comment: @Teocci is ok this is close to what i  looking for thank you for help